# HTML trouble linking CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit my HTML file called index.html using a css file called style.css which is located inside of /root/var/www/ and the html file i located in /root/var/www/html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div class="body">
  <head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
```

I think its because they are in two different folders and i tried googling the problem which made me try using `href="../style.css"` which also did not work.

Comment: ../style.css should have worked. The link tag is self closing. You don't have the forward slash. Try adding that.

Comment: Do you have the <link> inside the head element?

Comment: `<div class="body">
  <head>` is wrong

Comment: Yes, he needs to study proper html structure first! It is a mess. I assumed he typed out stuff really fast. That is the screenshot of his html.

Comment: @vcasso yes i do and im new first html project ever

Comment: @DanielVillanueva Don't forget to mark the answer that was the most helpful to you as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html should be structured like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also try `href="./../style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Your order and the hierarchy of tags is wrong: Start with `<html>` , then `<head>`, inside that put the link to the stylesheet (with `href="../style.css"`), but NO `div` yet, then close `</head>`, open `<body>` and then start with your DIVs etc., i.e. all the visible stuff. At the end close `</body>` and `</html>`